# Minimal working example of using Android's OverScroller class?

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-scroll, android-overscoll

I'm trying to understand how to use the `OverScroller` class in Android for smooth scrolling. While the documentation provides an overview, I'm having trouble piecing together a minimal working example from start to finish.

Could someone provide a simple and clear example of how to implement and use the `OverScroller` class in an Android project?

Comment: The Android Developer Docs' UI Guide on how to [Animate a scroll gesture](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/gestures/scroll) demonstrates the usage of `OverScroller` on a snippet taken from the [InteractiveChart](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/refs/heads/main/samples/training/InteractiveChart) sample. It's relatively compact, so I hope it helps you.